# Get the no. of rows returned from sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am writing an Oracle stored procedure with an `OUT` parameter as `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

The procedure does something like below:

1. `open ref_cursorA for select * from tableA`
2. save the no. of records retrieved to another table.
3. return the `ref_cursorA` for generating an Excel report.

However, there is no way to know the number of rows retrieved before fetching from the cursor, but I really need to save the no. of rows retrieved in the s.p. What should I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a cursor, the query hasn't been executed yet. It will be executed when you fetch the result rows. And most likely the execution will be piecewise, i.e. a few rows at a time.

So the number of rows is only know when the last row has been fetched.

If you really need the number of rows in your stored procedure, you'll have to execute an additional query that just counts the number of rows before you open and return the cursor for the main query:

1. `select count(*) into var from tableA`
2. Save the the number of rows in a separate table
3. `open ref_cursorA for select * from tableA`
4. return `cursorA`

Note:.Depending on your transaction isolation level, the `COUNT(*)` query will return a slightly different count if data is inserted and deleted at the same time.